# Custom label and textbox is not working for 508 compliance

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem like i need to my web pages to be 508 compliance,some of the lables and textboxes are custom created and that are not working in 508 test all other normal lable and textbox are working fine.
Can anybody help me how custom made textbox and label compliance with 508 test.

Thanks

Comment: You are going to have to post some code.  Please post any markup for controls that don't meet compliance, then we would be able to pinpoint what about them is not in compliance.

Answer (score 0):

For Labels :

```
aria-label="text that the screenreader should read out"
```

For textbox :

```
role="textbox"
```